How can I directly prove that a characterization of perfectly normal using $G_\delta$ sets implies completely normal?
There are several questions on Math.SE showing how perfectly normal implies completely normal. However, I am attempting to prove this fact without appealing to a characterization that requires the existence of a function mapping into the reals.
Instead, consider this characterization: a space is perfectly normal if and only if it is normal and closed sets are $G_\delta$ (countable intersections of open sets). How can one show directly that a space with this property is completely normal: given sets $S,T$ with $S\cap cl(T)=\emptyset$ and $cl(S)\cap T=\emptyset$, there exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $S\subseteq U$ and $T\subseteq V$.
(The restrictions here are due to my current effort to add the perfectly normal property to mathlib, so not all of "known" mathematics is at our disposal.)

Not sure, what you allowed yourself to use. What I would consider as a standard proof (compare partly Engelking) is as follows:

An $F_\sigma$ subset of a normal space is normal.
A space is completely normal, iff every open subset is normal.

If I'm not mistaken, both can be proven without using the reals.
Of course, 1. and 2. prove the claim.

That looks like a decent outline. I think I'd have to prove both statements for mathlib, but that would be a useful contribution itself. I'm still hopeful for a direct proof without lemmas, but maybe that's unreasonable.



https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277251/if-x-is-normal-and-a-is-a-f-sigma-set-in-x-then-a-is-normal-how-c


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723501/every-open-subspace-of-x-is-normal-implies-that-x-is-completely-normal



This result is now in mathlib. Here's how it was accomplished, in human language.
For any two subsets $S,T$ of a topological space, we say that a separating cover (HasSeparatingCover) for $S$ with respect to $T$ is a countable collection $\mathcal U=\{U_n:n<\omega\}$ of open sets such that $S\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal U$ and $T\cap cl(U_n)=\emptyset$ for each $n<\omega$.
It follows (hasSeparatingCovers_iff_separatedNhds) that $S$ and $T$ may be separated by open sets if and only if there exist a separating cover $\mathcal U$ for $S$ with respect to $T$ and a separating cover $\mathcal V$ for $T$ with respect to $S$. For the backwards direction, consider $\bigcup_{n<\omega}\left(U_n\setminus\bigcup_{m\leq n}cl (V_n)\right)$ and $\bigcup_{n<\omega}\left(V_n\setminus\bigcup_{m\leq n}cl (U_n)\right)$.
We then observe (Disjoint.hasSeparatingCover_closed_gdelta_right) that in a normal space with an arbitrary subset $S$ and a disjoint closed $G_\delta$ subset $T$, there exists a separating cover of $S$ with respect to $T$. To see this, let $T=\bigcap\{G_n:n<\omega\}$ for $G_n$ open, apply normality to pick $T\subseteq G_n'\subseteq cl(G_n')\subseteq G_n$, and then convince yourself that $\{X\setminus cl(G_n'):n<\omega\}$ is the desired separating cover.
Finally (PerfectlyNormalSpace.toCompletelyNormalSpace), mathlib defines perfectly normal spaces and completely normal spaces as described in the question. So by Disjoint.hasSeparatingCover_closed_gdelta_right, in any perfectly normal space and sets $S,T$ with $S\cap cl(T)=\emptyset$ and $cl(S)\cap T=\emptyset$, we may construct separating covers. Thus by hasSeparatingCovers_iff_separatedNhds, we have open sets separating $S$ and $T$.
